# AEM timeout in workflow participant step is not working as expected

Tags: osgi, aem

Facing issue while rescheduling AbsoluteTimeAutoAdvancer in workflow.

I created a custom workflow to schedule a press release email. For this I am adding "absoluteTime" metaData in workflow process step followed by AbsoluteTimeAutoAdvancer in participant step.It is scheduling as expected in this scenario.

But when I tried to reschedule same workflow instance by postponing the date, it is still getting executed for older time even after changing "absoluteTime" metaData to newer timestamp.

Is it possible to reschedule the workflow using AbsoluteTimeAutoAdvancer?

Please let me know if I am missing out anything.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Time out in participant step is working fine for the first time say 'time A', when I step back from inbox to previous step and change timeout to some other time say 'time B' then timeout is happening still on 'time A'. Is this is known issue in AEM or am I missing out anything?

Comment: Did you check if there is another time property that could be read instead of the absoluteTime?

Comment: No there is no other time stamp , AbsoluteTimeAutoAdvancer reads only absoluteTime as input.